# Tag synonym request for Microsoft-Lumia-950?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

Please create tag synonyms for

- [microsoft-lumia-950](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-lumia-950) -> [lumia-950](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-950)
- [microsoft-lumia-950-xl](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-lumia-950-xl) -> [lumia-950-xl](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-950-xl)

These were the tags I tried to use based on the established tagging of [nokia-lumia-model](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia-model). I do not mind which is the master. I just want the tagging to be easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those have been done, although nothing appeared to be tagged with the Microsoft prefixed options